# Color and label only two variables and exclude others

Tags: r, ggplot2

I’d like to know do two things:

1. Make the Nationality values 'Argentine' and 'Mexique' specific colors while all other values are black.
2. Have a legend that only shows 'Argentine' and 'Mexique'.

I was able to do the first part using scale_color_manual and assigning black to all the values except 'Argentine' and 'Mexique', but that seemed a bit cumbersome. Also, it doesn't solve the legend problem.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
ggplot(Factiva_Redux, aes(x=Argentina, y=Mexico, colour = Nationality))
+ geom_point(shape=1)
+ scale_y_log10(breaks = c(100, 1000, 10000, 100000), labels = c(100, 1000, 10000, 100000))
+ scale_x_continuous(trans='log2', breaks = c(10, 100, 500),labels = c(10, 100, 500))
+ xlab("Writer Mentions in Argentinian Newspapers")
+ ylab("Writer Mentions in Mexican Newspapers")
```

[image: 1 Writer mentions Argentina/Mexico]

Comment: Also check the `gghighlight` package. Link: https://yutannihilation.github.io/gghighlight/

Answer (score 0):

OP.  Since you have not supplied an example dataset to use, I'll make one and show you the approach that should work for your target.

```
set.seed(1234)

my_types <- paste0('Type',1:10)

df <- data.frame(
  x=sample(1:20, 100, replace=TRUE),
  y=sample(1:20, 100, replace=TRUE),
  type=sample(my_types, 100, replace=TRUE)
)
```

The default plot gives you something similar to your own:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + theme_classic() +
  geom_point(aes(color=type), size=2)
```

[image]

In this case, if I only wanted to highlight when `df$type` was equal to `Type1` and `Type2`, and leave the rest as gray dots, the simplest approach would be to have two calls to `geom_point`:  one where you define the color aesthetic for the highlighted types and the other for the gray points.  Note that in the code below, the `geom_point` for the highlighted types has `color=` within `aes()`, whereas the other has `color=` outside `aes()`.  The legend is only created for the points within `aes()`

```
# to define what we want to have colored
highlight_types <- c('Type1','Type2')

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + theme_classic() +
   geom_point(
     data=df[which(df$type %in% highlight_types),],
     aes(color=type), size=2) +
   geom_point(
     data=df[which(!(df$type %in% highlight_types)),],
     color='gray75', size=2, shape=3)
```

[image]